# Python IDLE shell - How to make multiline strings

Tags: python, python-idle

I am a beginner at Python and I know how to type the correct syntax but when I repeat it, it comes out with no extra lines, it just says "\n"

#### Details on example below

My variable is `fred` and I set it to what it says below, and then on the 3rd line I made it print the text.
Please tell me if I didn't describe it correctly, keep in mind I'm a beginner.

#### Example

```
>>> fred = '''How do dinosaurs pay their bills?
With tyrannosaurus checks!'''
>>> fred
'How do dinosaurs pay their bills?\nWith tyrannosaurus checks!'
```

I use Python 3.4.2 (shell) on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: It works for me. What os and python version you use?

Comment: Python 3.4.2 Shell, Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Ok. Im on Linux. So cant check. Maybe OS differences are the reason?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the correct behavior is to show the actual newline (and without quotes).  Something is wrong with your interpreter or you're not showing us the entire code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my interpreter does that too. I think it's normal. (for interpreters)

Comment: When I enter `fred` directly into the REPL, I get back the `\n` delimited string, but when I call `print(fred)` it prints on separate lines, as expected.  `sys.version` returns `'2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) \n[GCC 4.8.2]'`.  As @Rufflewind said, something is wrong with either your installation or your example.

Comment: @PangeaCake: the quotes and the `\n` should only appear if you type `fred` directly (or use `repr`), not when you call `print(fred)`.

Comment: @dimo414 Ok yeah I just tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` in that string represents the new line symbol. For pretty much all purposes, it *is* a new line.

What you're doing is correct.

To print the lines on separate lines:

```
for line in jack.split("\n"):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Ok in that case, is there a way to make it actually be multi-lined? (Like <br> in HTML)

Comment: put them into separate prints, like `map(print, jack.split("\n"))`. That's a little bit of a complicated way to do that actually, sorry, added info in answer.

Comment: Note the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function has nothing to do with map data structures (called [`dict`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) in Python).